# Apache Catalina Error:- "SEVERE: Error listenerStart"

Tags: catalina, atomikos

I am getting the following error when i tried to start a java spring software that runs under apache:-

```
Sep 24, 2012 12:08:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Sep 24, 2012 12:08:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/jw] startup failed due to previous errors
Sep 24, 2012 12:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive jwdesigner.war
Sep 24, 2012 12:08:21 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 24, 2012 12:08:21 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Sep 24, 2012 12:08:21 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Sep 24, 2012 12:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2251 ms
```

**So what might be causing this error.
BR**

:::UPDATED:::

The full error starts with the following, baring in mind that i am using windows 7 OS :-**

```
    Sep 24, 2012 12:18:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.18
Sep 24, 2012 12:18:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive jw.war
No properties path set - looking for transactions.properties in classpath...
transactions.properties not found - looking for jta.properties in classpath...
Failed to open transactions properties file - using default values
java.lang.RuntimeException
        at com.atomikos.util.UniqueIdMgr.<init>(UniqueIdMgr.java:112)
        at com.atomikos.util.UniqueIdMgr.<init>(UniqueIdMgr.java:88)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.StandAloneTransactionManager.<init>(St
andAloneTransactionManager.java:82)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.createDefaul
t(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:285)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTra
nsactionServiceImp.java:306)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransac
tionServiceImp.java:413)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager.checkSetup(UserTransac
tionManager.java:90)
        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager.init(UserTransactionMa
nager.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1375)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationCon
text(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationConte
xt(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitiali
zed(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
t.java:3843)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4
342)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:77
1)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:830)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:719
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1149)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:5
16)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
```

BR

Comment: Don't you have any other errors?  I think there is a listener that is configured in your web.xml file that did not start but the cause can be a million things.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, i have updated my original post with the full error. Best Regards

Answer (score 20):

Enable more detailed logging by creating a file `logging.properties` at `WEB-INF\classes\`
with the following content:

> > org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
> >
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

Now the offender should show up in the stack trace.

Reference:

> [Debugging the dreaded "SEVERE: Error listenerStart" AND "SEVERE: error filterStart" Tomcat Error messages](http://blog.trifork.com/2011/03/18/debugging-the-dreaded-severe-error-listenerstart-and-severe-error-filterstart-tomcat-error-messages/)

Comment: Note that those are two separate "org.apache.catalina..." lines.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an issue with the initialisation of atomikos.  Maybe the default values don't work properly for your application:

```
No properties path set - looking for transactions.properties in classpath...
transactions.properties not found - looking for jta.properties in classpath...
Failed to open transactions properties file - using default values
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, can u indicate how i can work on solving this issue?

Comment: I'm not an atomikos specialist but try searching the http://www.atomikos.com/ documentation.  What is clear is that you need to create a file in your classpath which contains your properties.

Comment: the strange this is that i use to run the application without any errors. but suddenly i got this error .BR

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are generating jdk 8 source code on your project or some library and deploying on a jdk 7 or jdk 6 server.